# How to see pages I have hidden from appearing in my Facebook newsfeed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, news-feed

My friends share a lot of quotes from random pages. It kind of clutters up my timeline and its annoying. So on the post I tap on the small down arrow and click on **Hide all from *page name***.

Now I want to see which all pages I have hidden from appearing in my newsfeed. How can I do that?

On my Android phone I went to News Feed Preferences, but it shows tabs of Summary, People, Pages & Groups. Under these tabs I only see statistical figures of how many posts I have seen of a friend.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a way currently to check this. The only list that is shown is a list of apps hidden.

[image: List of apps hidden]